Can I have an ordered list with both numbers and letters in it?
So I have a cell that contains three lists with line breaks separating them:
How the data is currently set up
Is there a way to make it so there is both a numbered and alphabetical list? E.g.

a. First Point b. Second Point c. Third Point
a. First Point b. Second Point c. Third Point
a. First Point b. Second Point c. Third Point

I've tried asking ChatGPT but it can never give me the answer I want.
I've tried using formulas given to me by ChatGPT such as:
=TEXTJOIN(" ", IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("a", I3)), ROW(), ""), "a") & ". " & SUBSTITUTE(I3, "a", "a", 1)
But that resulted in the following result:
The outcome of the above formula

Show your initial data as wel as your prefered/intended output, preferably in text format, using Markdown Table.

I think I know what you're trying to ask, but it's not really in your question. To be sure: what is your expected output and why post data as image instead of data (for instance as markdown table https://www.tablesgenerator.com/markdown_tables )

Would this be sufficient?

Formula in B1:
=LET(s,TEXTSPLIT(A1,,CHAR(10)),TEXTJOIN(CHAR(10),,SEQUENCE(ROWS(s))&". "&s))


As per comments, an edited version:

=LET(s,TEXTSPLIT(REDUCE(A1,27-SEQUENCE(26),LAMBDA(x,y,SUBSTITUTE(x,y,CHAR(y+96)))),,CHAR(10)),TEXTJOIN(CHAR(10),,SEQUENCE(ROWS(s))&". "&s))


Yes thank you! Is there a way to go from:

Thing 1 2. Thing 2 3. Thing 3 to what you've created? I put a substitute formula after this to get to: a. Thing 1 b. Thing 2 c. Thing 3 and then created this post.

Could there be a formula to do it all in one step or would I have to do the two steps like I mentioned?

I'm confused about that input. Care to elaborate? I'm very confident it will be possible @Audrix.

Yes sorry.
So in one cell, I have:
1. First Point 2. Second Point 3. Third Point.

I then used a substitue formula to get:
a. First Point b. Second Point c. Third Point.

And then I want it to be this:
1. a. First Point b. Second Point c. Third Point.

Is this possible in one command?

@Audrix, see edited answer.
